# Get contents from Kendo Editor in rich text format

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I am trying to send data from the kendo editor in an email but the email is displaying html tags. I believe the editor's content is Html, thus, by design its value() method also returns Html. I am struggling to figure out how to get  the text from the value.

In my function, I am sending the data like this: 

`"emailmessagehtml": $("#editor").val(),`

But this is displaying all the html tags in the email.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction to display the rich text content in the email.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the encodedValue() instead.

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
var content = editor.encodedValue();
```

[Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/methods/encodedvalue)

Check also https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/encoded

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  value: "<p>foo</p>",
  encoded: false
});
```

**encoded** Indicates whether the Editor should submit encoded HTML tags. By default, the submitted value is encoded.